# How to construct a guess solution to Linear Non-Homogeneous DE s

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

http://www.imgim.com/237.png 
http://www.imgim.com/p237_7.jpg
The solution is above. However I don't see how to decide what is correct guess solution. I thought there are $t,t^2$ in general solution so my guess solution should be $At^3$. Then I checked solution and saw it is supposed to be $t^3(At+B)$. What is the logic beyond constructing guess solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In general (for a constant-coefficient linear DE), suppose the non-homogeneous term is $f(t) = P(t) \exp(\lambda t)$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $d$.  If $\lambda$ is not a root of the characteristic polynomial (so $\exp(\lambda t)$ is not a solution of the homogeneous equation), then there will be a solution of the non-homogeneous equation of the form $Q(t) \exp(\lambda t)$ where $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $d$.  If $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of multiplicity $r$, then
$t^k \exp(\lambda t)$ are solutions of the homogeneous equation for $k = 0,1,\ldots, r-1$, and there will be a solution of the non-homogeneous equation of the form $t^r Q(t) \exp(\lambda t)$, where $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $d$.

In your case, the characteristic polynomial
$C(\lambda) = \lambda^6 - \lambda^3 = \lambda^3 (\lambda^3 - 1)$.  This has a factor $\lambda^3$, so $\lambda=0$ is a root of multiplicity $r=3$, and $P(t) = t$ has degree $d=1$, so you look for a solution of the form $t^3 Q(t) =t^3 (A t + B)$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand $t^3$ part. However (At+B) is still blurry.

Comment: What's blurry about it?  It's the general polynomial of degree $1$.

Comment: I know but why we use it? Where it come from? Why don't we write $At^3+Bt^2+Ct+D$ instead of $t^3(At+B)$

Comment: Because $r = 3$ and $d = 1$.